# Swift: Get localized time display - with separate AM/PM in 12 hours regions

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I would like to display the time of the current date in a UILabel in the current locale. Assuming the current time would be 15:30 (24 hours display) / 3:30 PM (12 hours display). Now, if the current locale of the user is 12 hours display, the label should only show "3:30", and the "PM" should display in a second label. I intended to use

```
someDateTime = Date()
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
df.timeStyle = .short
timeLabel.text =  df.string(from: someDateTime) // how without AM/PM ?
ampmLabel.text = "???" // how to show only in 12 hours regions?
```

But in 12 hours regions it comes always with the AM/PM attached to it. How could I easily distinguish these cases?

Comment: Without going through some sub stringing, I doubt it can be achieved automatically

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to generate the time string from your date formatter and then see if the resulting string contains either the `amSymbol` or `pmSymbol` of the date formatter. If it does, save off that symbol and remove it from the date string. Then you will have the two strings you need.

```
let timeDF = DateFormatter()
timeDF.locale = ... // whatever you need of other than the user's current
timeDF.dateStyle = .none
timeDF.timeStyle = .short
var timeStr = timeDF.string(from: Date())
var ampmStr = ""
if let rng = timeStr.range(of: timeDF.amSymbol) {
    ampmStr = timeDF.amSymbol
    timeStr.removeSubrange(rng)
} else if let rng = timeStr.range(of: timeDF.pmSymbol) {
    ampmStr = timeDF.pmSymbol
    timeStr.removeSubrange(rng)
}

timeLabel.text = timeStr.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
ampmLabel.text = ampmStr
```

Comment: thanks, that could work if I set the locale to the current user's one (cause I need to display the time with the current user's locale). Could you maybe add this, so I can mark complete? It is a bit string analysis though - I thought there would be a cleaner way by finding out if the current user's locale would use AM/PM (12hours) or 24 hours system...

Comment: If you want the user's current locale then there is no need to set the date formatter's locale because it defaults to the user's current locale.

Comment: If you simply want to know if the user's locale uses AM/PM you can look at the value of `timeDF.format` after setting the `timeStyle`. If the format contains `"a"` then the locale uses AM/PM. But also note this is also affected by the user's settings such as the 12/24 hour setting. This can override the locale's default setting.